# Disable actionPoller with Javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, actionpoller

I have an actionPoller visualforce component rerendering an output panel every 5 seconds. This works fine, however when I switch to another outputPanel 5 seconds later the action poller will rerender the first panel and place it above the second panel.

How can I use Javascript / jQuery to enable / disable whether the actionPoller is enabled?

Comment: I recommend you control the `enabled` attribute on your `<apex:actionPoller>` tag with a property on your controller. When you switch tabs, simply set the property to `false`.

Comment: Thank you Adrian. I took this approach and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you control the `enabled` attribute on your `<apex:actionPoller>` tag with a `Boolean` property on your controller. When you switch tabs, simply set the property to false. Something like:

```
public Boolean shouldPoll { get; set; }
<apex:actionPoller enabled="{!shouldPoll}" ...>
```